# DNX on LEGO Mindstorms

Tags: ev3, programming, monobrick

I am not familiar with ARM development but I am wondering would it be possible to compile DNX against LEGO Mindstorms EV3 processor. I know there is some ARM support and even there are some builds against it (nuget packages for arm architecture for asp.net-5) but I don't know if there are any differences between ARM processors that would prevent doing this on LEGO.

I know that there are projects like lejos that compile java runtime and run it on LEGO brick. There is Mono Brick project that runs mono runtime and uses mono libraries. DNX is also open source so I would believe that can be done.

So my question is if DNX currently support this or it would need some serious rewrite?

Can https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/tree/dev/src/dnx.coreclr.unix project be used as a startup point?

I am currently interested only in some very simple implementation runtime that bootstrap a simple .net application on EV3 brick. No sensors are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally possible, see the link and issue tracker here :
https://twitter.com/shanselman/status/667144339353526272
https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/3145

Comment: Cool I like links to my own work ;)